# Is there any way to put the whole code inside of void function to for loop in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm curios on why when I put the whole code inside void max_heap to for loop of void build_maxheap, program does not work. The for loop just repeat what is the code inside vode max_heap then why does it not work if it works when I put the void function? Is there anyway I can put the whole code inside the max_heap to the for loop of void build_maxheap and run the program fine?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void max_heap(int *a, int m) {
   int j, t;
   t = a[m];
   j = 2 * m;
   while (j <= 10) {
      if (j < 10 && a[j+1] > a[j])
         j = j + 1;
      if (t > a[j])
         break;
      else if (t <= a[j]) {
         a[j / 2] = a[j];
         j = 2 * j;
      }
   }
   a[j/2] = t;
   return;
}
void build_maxheap(int *a,int ) {
   int k;
   for(k = 10/2; k >= 1; k--) {
      max_heap(a,k);
   }
}
int main() {
   int  i, a[10];
   
   
   for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      cout << "Enter num:";
      cin>>a[i];
   }
   build_maxheap(a,10);
   cout<<"\nMax Heap \n" << endl;
   for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
   }
}
```

Im having a hard time converting my program from O(N) to O(N log N). Is there any problem in my loop?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void max_heap(int *a, int m) {
   int j, t;
   t = a[m];
   j = 2 * m;
   while (j <= 10) {
      if (j < 10 && a[j+1] > a[j])
         j = j + 1;
      if (t > a[j])
         break;
      else if (t <= a[j]) {
         a[j / 2] = a[j];
         j = 2 * j;
      }
   }
   a[j/2] = t;
   return;
}
void build_maxheap(int *a,int ) {
   int k;
   for(k = 10/2; k >= 1; k--) {
      max_heap(a,k);
   }
}
int main() {
   int  i, a[10];
   
   for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      
      cin>>a[i];
   }
   build_maxheap(a,10);
   cout<<"Max Heap - O(N log N)\n";
   for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      cout<<a[i]<<endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that array indexes are zero-based. So an array of `10` elements have indexes from `0` to `9`.

Comment: "I'm curios on why when I put the whole code inside void max_heap to for loop of void build_maxheap, program does not work." if thats the question you should show that code and explain how it "does not work". It is not clear what is the difference between the two codes you posted or what exactly your question is

Comment: "Im having a hard time converting my program from O(N) to O(N log N)." you don't "convert a program from O(N) to O(N log N)" by merely moving code from one function to another. Reduction of complexity requires a different algorithm, not just refactoring of the source code

Comment: A program in O(N) is also in O(N log N) (but not necessarily the other way around)